# Dismiss UIScrollView based on touch coordinates on UIImageView embedded into the UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

There is a `UITableView` with many photos. As a photo is tapped, a `modalView` is presented with `UIScrollView`, which further has an `UIImageView` embedded into it. The tapped image is presented here (similar to the Facebook app).
Now, i can move the image vertically using `touchesMoved` and `CGRectMake`.
What i want to achieve is that when i drag the image vertically, on reaching a certain threshold, the ImageView & ScrollView should disappear and we should be back to the tableView.

Image moved using:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches
        withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pos = [touch locationInView: [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
    NSLog(@"%f", pos.y);

if (pos.y>50&&pos.y<430){
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4

                     animations:^{_photoImageView.frame=CGRectMake(0,pos.y-100,320,200);}

                     completion:^(BOOL finished){ }];
}
}
```

The action to return control to the tableView is needed here:

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint pos = [touch locationInView: [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

if (pos.y>50&&pos.y<430){
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4

                     animations:^{_photoImageView.frame=CGRectMake(0,140,320,200);}

                     completion:^(BOOL finished){ }];
}
else if(pos.y<50||pos.y>430)
    //Code needed here !!
    ;
}
```

Further, if transparency can be achieved on the `imageView` background (i.e. Scrollview) such that the table view is visible with certain Alpha, that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: are you adding UIView or UIViewController

Comment: [view removeFromSuperView]; you didn't try this where view is your scroll view

Comment: I already did. I think i'm misplacing the 'removeFromSuperView', or using the wrong view instance. Hoping for alternate solution.

[PS. project based on FacebookSDK.framework.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dismiss with `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` (should use the newer method `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`).

(This was assuming you presented with `presentModalViewController:animated:`, just adding a view to the screen is not a modal presentation). If you didn't really present a modal then just use `removeFromSuperview`.

When presenting a view modally the view below will be removed from display (it's expected not to be visible), so if you make the modal view transparent you will just see black below it. If you want to make the overlay view transparent you should just make it a subview, set the opacity (`alpha`) and use `bringSubviewToFront:`.

Comment: If it were up to me, i'd use subviews only. I am prejudiced against using Modals. They lack the flexibility desired.